# Case Duplication on After Event

Tags: apex, trigger, case

I took this code from cookbook but the problem is it's throwing error message before the record gets inserted.Do we have an option of writing an trigger including (**Before and After events** ).While using the **Before Events** , it should throw an Error as it is duplicate record and when using the **After Events** , it should save the Duplicate record and then Close it.
Any help is very much appreciated.

**Here is the Code for the Before Event :**

```
trigger CaseDuplicatePreventer on Case(before insert, before update) {  
  Map<String, Case> CaseMap = new Map<String, Case>();   
 for (Case c : System.Trigger.new) {                
 // Make sure we don't treat an Subject address that         // isn't changing during an update as a duplicate.              
if ((c.Subject != null) &&               
 (System.Trigger.isInsert || (c.Subject != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Subject))) {                    
 // Make sure another new Case isn't also a duplicate                  
if (CaseMap.containsKey(c.Subject)) {                
c.Subject.addError('Another new Case has the ' + 'same Subject address.');

  } else {                
CaseMap.put(c.Subject, c);           
 }       }    }         
// Using a single database query, find all the Cases in          // the database that have the same Subject address as any          // of the Cases being inserted or updated.         
 for (Case c : [SELECT Email,Subject FROM Case WHERE Subject IN :CaseMap.KeySet()]) {        
Case newCase = CaseMap.get(c.Subject);        
newCase.Subject.addError('A Case with this Subject'  + 'address already exists.'); 

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your first line you need to populate the case map first with a query, so that it can be used in the line: 
if (CaseMap.containsKey(c.Subject)) ....

Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.This code works fyn for the Before Events.Similarily i would like to have a code for After Events.Where we can include the Before and After Events and execute the code.